# How to pass a graph data structure to the subproblem in SCIP?

Tags: c++, scip

I have a question about branch and price in SCIP! I have a heuristic to solve my sub-problem, and the input to this heuristic is a bipartite graph. The structure of this graph is dependent on the variables fixing by branching rule, so it is different in each node. My question is how I can pass this graph to the sub-problem appropriately? Do I have to use something similar to constraint handler or there is a better way to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: if I remember correctly, you are writing in C++, correct? Please mention this in every question, you will get better answers.

Comment: The [TSP-example](http://scip.zib.de/doc-3.1.0/examples/TSP/index.php) uses a graph for generating cuts. The graph implementation header is `GomoryHuTree.h`, and the graph is stored in the problem data `ProbDataTSP.h`.

Comment: yes, I write code in c++, I will look at these files, thank you.